# add-apt-repository command not working

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, sudo

I'm new to Ubuntu and I tried to install something and the guide I was reading says to run a command that starts with

```
sudo add-apt-repository
```

but whenever I try to use the command then it says

```
bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

whether I start it with `sudo` or not, and I can't seem to find any help anywhere else.